# For loop not returning correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop

Why is this for look let returning the correct number of "$" ?

```
const DollarSignRating = price => {
        if (!price || price === 0) {
          return "$";
        }
      
        let dollarSigns = "";
      
        for (let i = 1; i < price; i++) {
          dollarSigns += "$";
        }
        return dollarSigns;
    };
```

how it's being rendered :

```
<DollarSignRating price={Math.round(props.restaurant.priceLevels)}/>
```

Comment: I don't think that's how react works ... what did you base this code on?

Answer (score 0):

You have defined a function and used it as a component!
if you call `DollarSignRating(Number)` it works correctly. but if you want to use it as a component use this

```
export defaul DollarSignRating = ({price}) => {
        if (!price || price === 0) {
          return <h1>"$"</h1>;
        }
      
        let dollarSigns = "";
      
        for (let i = 1; i < price; i++) {
          dollarSigns += "$";
        }
        return <h1>{dollarSigns}</h1>;
    };
```

in each component, you should return an `html` code like `h1`.
now you can use it as follows:

```
<DollarSignRating price={your number} />
```

Comment: yeah but it's still not adding an additional $ sigh.

Comment: What do you want exactly? Your code generates $ sign, based on your number, for example for price = 3 it will return $$$.